# PostgreSQL Cursor to update table

Tags: postgresql, cursor, datediff

I have a table that represents medical examinations for patients, it has ID of the examination and patient ID.

I want to run through the table row by row and take every patient ID and compare its different consultations to see if it is considered as a "new_attack". I'm dealing with Malaria disease and we consider that every patient who has a consultation in the past 60 days and who is positive to the test as an old case and `new_attack = false`, otherwise `new_attack = true`.

But I have to take in consideration the column `palufalci` when I go through the table because a patient can have a medical examination but not positive to the malaria test and in this case `new_attack = false`.

Here is the code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbl_diagnostiques_guy (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tbl_diagnostiques_guy_id_seq'::regclass),
  dateconsultation date,
  numeropatient character varying(13),
  palufalci boolean,
  new_attack boolean
);
```

I used this query to calculate `datediff` between 2 medical examination of every patient:

```
SELECT id, numeropatient, palufalci,
    dateconsultation, NextDate,
    date(NextDate) - date(dateconsultation) as Diff, new_attack
FROM (
  SELECT id, numeropatient, palufalci, dateconsultation, new_attack,
         (SELECT  MIN(dateconsultation) 
          FROM    tbl_diagnostiques_guy T2
          WHERE   T2.numeropatient = T1.numeropatient
          AND     T2.dateconsultation > T1.dateconsultation
         ) AS NextDate
  FROM tbl_diagnostiques_guy T1) AS T
WHERE NextDate IS NOT NULL AND (date(NextDate) - date(dateconsultation) < 60)
GROUP BY id, numeropatient, palufalci, dateconsultation, NextDate, new_attack
ORDER BY numeropatient DESC;
```

and the result is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZfDK.jpg)

Now I want to know how to update the table and obtain the result that I want.

Comment: Does table `tbl_diagnostiques_guy` have a column `palufalci` or `vivax`? The query seems to suggest the former but your table definition has the latter. Please *edit* your question (see link under the tags of the question) and then also put a text version of the output (export to file in PgAdminIII) instead of a link to a graphic.

Comment: Hello, first I would like to thank you for editing my post.
It's palufalci I edited the question.

Comment: Hello Anass and welcome to SO. See my answer below. Good luck with your database and research, I have had malaria twice myself so keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from your question that you want to populate the `new_attack` column with values. That is quite easily done with your query - although your logic to set the `new_attack` value seems missing - but there is actually a more elegant form using the [`lag()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT id, numeropatient, palufalci, dateconsultation,
       CASE WHEN days IS NULL OR days > 60 THEN false
       ELSE palufalci AND old_test
       END AS new_attack
FROM (
  SELECT id, numeropatient, palufalci, lag(palufalci) OVER w AS old_test,
         dateconsultation, dateconsultation - lag(dateconsultation) OVER w AS days,
  FROM tbl_diagnostiques_guy
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY numeropatient ORDER BY dateconsultation) ) sub;
```

Run that statement to verify that it does what you expect. If satisfied, then you can easily rework the whole thing into an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_diagnostiques_guy t
SET new_attack =
       CASE WHEN days IS NULL OR days > 60 THEN false
       ELSE palufalci AND old_test
       END
FROM (
  SELECT id, numeropatient, palufalci, lag(palufalci) OVER w AS old_test,
         dateconsultation, dateconsultation - lag(dateconsultation) OVER w AS days,
  FROM tbl_diagnostiques_guy
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY numeropatient ORDER BY dateconsultation) ) sub
WHERE t.id = sub.id; -- add other join conditions as required
```

Let's look at the `new_attack` logic in a bit more detail:

```
CASE WHEN days IS NULL OR days > 60 THEN false
ELSE palufalci AND old_test
END
```

The first line `WHEN days IS NULL OR days > 60 THEN false` means: If the previous consultation is more than 60 days ago or this is the first consultation (the `lag()` function will return `NULL` for the first consultation because there is no previous row), then the `new_attack` value is `false`.

The second line `palufalci AND old_test` means: If there was a second consultation within 60 days then `new_attack` is `true` only if both the previous and the current tests are `true`.

Comment: Your answer provides 70% of the solution i'm seeking. I think that it is my fault because I didn't mention that in case we have a new consultation we have to compare it to the previous one that is new_attack=true. First we take all first consultations of all the patients and make them new_attack=true, then the consultation that comes after should be compared to the new_attack=true.

Comment: Working just fine after adding some other rules, Thanks Patrick